# Move files automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, jscript

I'm after a script which automatically scans a folder (every 2 minutes) and when a file appears in that folder it will automatically move it (not copy) to another folder. 
Any ideas? Can this be achived by a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), you can write:

```
robocopy sourcefolder destinationfolder /mov /MOT:2
```

optional: add `/s` for including subdirectories

A possible location would be a link the autorun folder, select "run minimized" in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

2 minutes = 120 sec.

```
for /l %%a in (0) do (
    if exist "folder\*" move "folder\*" "elsewhere"
    ping -n 121 localhost > nul
)
```

Comment: Sorry Endoro, I did not get it, where should i place this script so that it works automatically without my interference. Thanks.